# How can I recover from a frozen app when connecting over VNC

Tags: 10.10, vnc, remote-control, kill

I have a htpc running 10.10.

It has no keyboard or mouse attached, so I connect over vnc for administration and manual tasks. This usually works fine but every so often an app running in fullscreen mode crashes.

All I want to be able to do is kill this app from VNC. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this that will preserve the VNC connection?

If I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I see the terminal but can no longer control it from VNC. Trying to return to the desktop doesn't work either?

Any easy process I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there's a way to do it from VNC, but if you can ssh into the server you can kill the process.

Use `ps -A` to list all running processes. You can use `grep` to prune the list if you know what you're looking for. Then use `kill <pid>` to kill the process, or `killall <name>` to kill all processes with that name.